# ssh: connect to host (myHostName) port 22: Connection timed out when access project via ssh cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, server, cpanel

I'm trying to access Laravel project from my local machine to run commands inside project like terminal, I've tried to access project folders from my local machine like this:

[image]

but I get this error:

**ssh: connect to host (myHostName) port 22: Connection timed out when access project via ssh cpanel**

also I've tried to access (Terminal) from C-panel but there is no terminal appear I don't know how does C-panel without a Terminal:

[image]

I tried to Generate new key in (ssh access) but don't know how to use it to access the folders to run commands inside the project like terminal??

could you help me to appear terminal in C-panel or access the project folders to run a command via ssh in my local machine terminal?

Comment: Try with port 4000 for ssh to a cPanel server. In WHM cpanel functions can be disabled, so if its not in the menu, you don't have access to it

Comment: Thanks for reply but there is no option to change port in C-panel

Comment: Not in cpanel, but where you make the connection

Comment: in my local machine